# How to install scipy on rhel 6.3

Tags: scipy, rhel, anaconda

How would you recommend I install the scipy stack on a RHEL 6.3? I tried the Anaconda distribution, which seems to install fine, however the tests for scipy fail miserably (tests for numpy work):

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.test()
Running unit tests for scipy
NumPy version 1.7.1
NumPy is installed in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
SciPy version 0.13.2
SciPy is installed in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy
Python version 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:47:18) [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
nose version 1.3.0
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:139: DeprecationWarning: `scipy.lib.blas` is deprecated, use `scipy.linalg.blas` instead!
  warnings.warn(depdoc, DeprecationWarning)
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:139: DeprecationWarning: `scipy.lib.lapack` is deprecated, use `scipy.linalg.lapack` instead!
  warnings.warn(depdoc, DeprecationWarning)
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................K..................................................................................................................K.......................................................................................K..K......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................SSSSSS......SSSSSS......SSSS......................................................................................0-th dimension must be fixed to 3 but got 15
..0-th dimension must be fixed to 3 but got 5
..................................K..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................K....................................................................................................................................................................Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: a first shot at debugging this would be to check which part of scipy fails. Try `>>> from scipy import linalg; linalg.test()` etc

Comment: This problem is due to a rarely-encountered gfortran compiler bug that is fixed in a later version of gfortran.  This should be fixed in the next release of Anaconda.  The test that is failing is a new feature in 0.13 and should not affect you if you don't use the new feature.  You can just skip the test by using @numpy.dec.skipif(True) on the test_rand method of the TestInterpolativeDecomposition class around line 230 of the scipy/linalg/tests/test_interpolative.py file.